# Stop MapStateToProps executing on screen load

Tags: react-native, redux

I have created a register page and I am trying hook up a loading ticker while I create the user account.

I am running into an issue where mapStateToProps() is being executed whenever the screen loads meaning that any values I have being mapped error as the state is undefined. None of my reducers or actions are executing to cause mapStateToProps() to run. Have I set something within my screen to cause this to execute, I completely understand that my state is indeed undefined but why does mapStateToProps even run in the initial load?

```
.......
interface State {
  name: string,
  email: string;
  mobileNo: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConf: string;
  nameTouched: boolean;
  emailTouched: boolean;
  mobileNoTouched: boolean;
  passwordTouched: boolean;
  passwordConfTouched: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
}
class RegisterScreen extends React.Component<{
  navigation: any;
  register: Function}, State> {

  emailInputRef = React.createRef<FormTextInput>();
  mobileNoInputRef = React.createRef<FormTextInput>();
  passwordInputRef = React.createRef<FormTextInput>();
  passwordConfInputRef = React.createRef<FormTextInput>();

  readonly state: State = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    mobileNo:"",
    passwordConf: "",
    emailTouched: false,
    passwordTouched: false,
    nameTouched: false,
    mobileNoTouched: false,
    passwordConfTouched: false,
    loading: false
  };

  handleNameChange = (name: string) => {
    this.setState({ name: name });
  };

  handleEmailChange = (email: string) => {
    this.setState({ email: email });
  };

  handleMobileNoChange = (mobileNo: string) => {
    this.setState({ mobileNo: mobileNo });
  };

  handlePasswordChange = (password: string) => {
    this.setState({ password: password });
  };

  handlePasswordConfChange = (passwordConf: string) => {
    this.setState({ passwordConf: passwordConf });
  };

  handleNameSubmitPress = () => {
    if (this.emailInputRef.current) {
      this.emailInputRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  handleEmailSubmitPress = () => {
    if (this.mobileNoInputRef.current) {
      this.mobileNoInputRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  handleMobileNoSubmitPress = () => {
    if (this.passwordInputRef.current) {
      this.passwordInputRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  handlePasswordSubmitPress = () => {
    if (this.passwordConfInputRef.current) {
      this.passwordConfInputRef.current.focus();
    }
  };

  handleNameBlur = () => {
  this.setState({ nameTouched: true });
  };

  handleEmailBlur = () => {
    this.setState({ emailTouched: true });
  };

  handleMobileNoBlur = () => {
    this.setState({ mobileNoTouched: true });
  };

  handlePasswordBlur = () => {
    this.setState({ passwordTouched: true });
  };

  handlePasswordConfBlur = () => {
    this.setState({ passwordConfTouched: true });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      name,
      email,
      password,
      mobileNo,
      passwordConf,
      emailTouched,
      passwordTouched,
      nameTouched,
      mobileNoTouched,
      passwordConfTouched,
    } = this.state;
    const nameError =
    !name && nameTouched
      ? strings.NAME_REQUIRED
      : undefined;
    const emailError =
      !email && emailTouched
        ? strings.EMAIL_REQUIRED
        : undefined;
    const mobileError =
    !mobileNo && mobileNoTouched
      ? strings.MOBILE_REQUIRED
      : undefined;
    const passwordError =
      !password && passwordTouched
        ? strings.PASSWORD_REQUIRED
        : undefined;
    const passwordConfError =
      !passwordConf && passwordConfTouched && (password === passwordConf)
        ? strings.PASSWORD_CONF_REQUIRED
        : undefined;
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        style={styles.container}
        behavior="padding"
      >
        <Image source={imagePath} style={styles.logo} />
        <View style={styles.form}>
        {/* Name */}
        <FormTextInput
            keyboardType={"default"}
            value={this.state.name}
            onChangeText={this.handleNameChange}
            onSubmitEditing={this.handleNameSubmitPress}
            placeholder={strings.NAME_PLACEHOLDER}
            autoCorrect={false}
            returnKeyType="next"
            onBlur={this.handleNameBlur}
            error={nameError}
          />
          {/* Email */}
          <FormTextInput
            keyboardType={"email-address"}
            ref={this.emailInputRef}
            value={this.state.email}
            onChangeText={this.handleEmailChange}
            onSubmitEditing={this.handleEmailSubmitPress}
            placeholder={strings.EMAIL_PLACEHOLDER}
            autoCorrect={false}
            returnKeyType="next"
            onBlur={this.handleEmailBlur}
            error={emailError}
          />
          {/* MobileNo */}
          <FormTextInput
            keyboardType={"numeric"}
            ref={this.mobileNoInputRef}
            value={this.state.mobileNo}
            onChangeText={this.handleMobileNoChange}
            onSubmitEditing={this.handleMobileNoSubmitPress}
            placeholder={strings.MOBILE_PLACEHOLDER}
            autoCorrect={false}
            returnKeyType="next"
            onBlur={this.handleMobileNoBlur}
            error={mobileError}
          />
          {/* Password */}
          <FormTextInput
            keyboardType={"default"}
            ref={this.passwordInputRef}
            value={this.state.password}
            onChangeText={this.handlePasswordChange}
            onSubmitEditing={this.handlePasswordSubmitPress}
            placeholder={strings.PASSWORD_PLACEHOLDER}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            returnKeyType="done"
            onBlur={this.handlePasswordBlur}
            error={passwordError}
          />
          {/* Password Conf */}
          <FormTextInput
            keyboardType={"default"}        
            ref={this.passwordConfInputRef}
            value={this.state.passwordConf}
            onChangeText={this.handlePasswordConfChange}
            placeholder={strings.PASSWORD_CONF_PLACEHOLDER}
            secureTextEntry={true}
            returnKeyType="done"
            onBlur={this.handlePasswordConfBlur}
            error={passwordConfError}
          />
          <ActivityIndicator animating={true} />
          <Button
            title="Register"
            onPress={() => this.props.register(
                name,
                email,
                mobileNo,
                password)}
            disabled={!email || !password || !name || !password || !passwordConf}
          />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(this.state);
 //On screen load this executes with state = undefined, not sure what's causing it to fire
  return {
   loading : state.creatingUser
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({register: register}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RegisterScreen);
```

Comment: mapStateToProps is _supposed_ to run on a page load that's it's default behavior and is quite useful. It's how when navigating, the proper UI (for example) is maintained between pages/components for, say, a logged in user. To disable that behavior would not only likely be an anti-pattern but have unexpected side effects. I'm sure there is a way to get what you want without disrupting the intended behavior of mapStateToProps... But I'm a little unclear of the current behavior vrs desired behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Redux tries to improve performance by doing shallow equality reference checks on incoming props in shouldComponentUpdate but you need to remember that 
shouldComponentUpdate method is not called for the initial render therfore mapStateToProps will run in the initial load